# A few questions on homeomorphisms

Tags: general-topology

I have been given the following questions on homeomorphisms, in particular showing the following spaces are not homeomorphic:

$S^{1}$ and $[0,1]$,

The letter 'X' and the letter 'Y',

$S^{2}$ and the torus.

I feel with these questions it is easy to explain intuitively why they are not homeomorphic, but am looking for more solid mathematical reasoning.

For example, with the first one, I believe if we remove a point from $[0,1]$ (except $0$ or $1$) then the space has become disconnected, whilst removing any point from $S^{1}$ still gives us a connected space. But how do I show this space is still connected?

Going on to the second problem it is clear if we remove the point in the middle of the 'X' the remaining space consists of 4 connected components, whilst there is no way to do this for the letter 'Y', but again I am not sure how to put this mathematically into a solid proof rather then explanation. The same applies to the final problem in that any closed curve in $S^2$ could be contracted to a point whilst this is not true for the torus.

Answer (score 1):

For the first two, to make your idea rigorous, you just assume there were a homeomorphism from one to the other.  For example, say $f:[0,1]\to S^1$.  Then removing $1/2$ gives a homeomorphism $f:[0,1/2)\cup (1/2,1]\to S^1-f(1/2)$.  It doesn't matter what $f(1/2)$ is, S^1 with a point removed is still connected.  This gives a contradiction.

For the last one the easiest tool is the fundamental group, but I'm guessing you haven't seen this before.  But again you can suppose there is a homeomorphism and use it to pass a homotopy from one to the other to make your idea rigorous.

Comment: Thank you, I am just about to begin studying the Fundamental Group so have yet to see it. When you say 'pass a homotopy' do you just mean that homeomorphic implies homotopy-equivalent. So my idea of a proof would be: Suppose $S^{2}$ homeomorphic to the torus. Then $S^{2}$ is homotopic to the torus. But $S^{2}$ is simply connected but the torus is not, thus the spaces can not be homotopy-equivalent giving a contradiction?

Comment: @AlexBowring that proof works.  I was thinking just to literally take a path on the torus, pull it back to a path on $S^1$, choose a homotopy to a point, and use $f$ to give a homotopy to a point on $T^2$ showing that $T^2$ is therefore simply connected, which is a contradiction.  But this is just basically how one can prove that that simple connectivity is a homeomorphism invariant.  If you already know about homotopy equivalence then you can just skip those details.

Answer (score 1):

The basic fact for "connectedness based" non-homeomorphism proofs:

(*) Let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ be a homeomorphism between spaces $X,Y$. Then for any $p \in X$, $f|_{X\setminus \{p\}}: X\setminus \{p\} \rightarrow Y \setminus \{f(p)\}$ is also a homeomorphism.

The proof is simply using the facts that the restricted map is still a bijection between their domain and codomain, the restriction of the continuous $f$ is still continuous (restricting in domain and in codomain both preserve continuity), and the same holds for the continuous inverse $f^{-1}$.

So suppose $f: [0,1] \rightarrow S^1$ is a homeomorphism. Apply (*) to $p=\frac{1}{2}$. Then $[0,1]\setminus \{{1 \over 2}\}$ is disconnected and $S^1 \setminus \{f({1 \over 2})\}$ is connected (whatever the image points is). So they cannot be homeomorphic, contradiction to the assumption of the original homeomorphism.

Suppose $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is a homeomorphism, where $X$ is the letter "X", $Y$ the letter "Y", as subspaces of the plane. Then when $p$ is the centre of the "X", then $X \setminus \{p\}$ has 4 connected components. While $Y \setminus \{f(p)\}$ has at most 3 different connected components, so these smaller spaces can never be homeomorphic, contradiction.

The last can be based on algebraic topology, or generalise (*) to subsets $A$ and $f[A]$ instead of points and their image (same proof, essentially), and use that we can remove a copy of the circle $S^1$ from a torus and leave a connected space (leaving an open cylinder) while any homeomorphic copy of a circle removed from $S^2$ makes it disconnected, by the Jordan Curve Theorem.

So suppose $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is a homeomorphism, where $X$ is the torus, $Y$ is $S^2$ and $A \subset X$ a copy of $S^1$ so that $X \setminus A$ is connected. Then $f|_{X\setminus A}$ is a homeomorphism between (connected) $X \setminus A$ and $Y \setminus f[A]$, and $f[A]$ is also a homeomorphic copy of $S^1$. But, as said, $Y \setminus f[A]$ is disconnected, so contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Use the fact that homeomorphisms preserve connected components. So a circle and the unit interval are not homeomorphic because removing the middle point from the interval gives ttwo connected components but removing any point from the circle gives one. Similarly removing the center point from X gives four connected components but removing any point from Y gives 2 or 3 components.